# Considering that we don't want logs, what files should I put into my MariaDB's file-based backup plan?

Tags: backup, mariadb

This is the content of my `Databases` directory:

```
total 201M
drwxr-xr-x 23 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 27 02:07 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 root             root             4.0K Jun  1 10:20 ..
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 12 16:31 Accounts
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 12 16:31 Aggregates
-rw-rw----  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  17M May 31 07:03 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump   52 May 31 07:03 aria_log_control
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 12 16:31 Blog
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 12 16:31 Configuration
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 26 10:07 Contacts
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 26 10:11 Contents
-rw-r--r--  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  509 Feb 26 10:11 db.sultanimmubin.ir.conf
-rw-rw----  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump    9 May 21 02:05 ddl_recovery-backup.log
-rw-rw----  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump    9 May 27 02:06 ddl_recovery.log
-rw-r--r--  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 1.2K Feb 26 10:11 docker-compose.yml
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K Apr 12 14:54 Entities
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 12 16:31 Forms
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K Apr 12 14:51 Galleries
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 26 10:06 Geo
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 12 16:31 Globalization
-rw-rw----  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 7.6K May 27 02:01 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-rw----  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  76M May 27 02:01 ibdata1
-rw-rw----  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  96M May 31 07:05 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  12M May 27 02:07 ibtmp1
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 26 10:08 Media
-rw-rw----  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump    0 Feb 26 09:57 multi-master.info
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K Feb 26 09:57 mysql
-rw-r--r--  1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump   15 Feb 26 09:57 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 12 16:31 Navigation
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K Feb 26 09:56 performance_schema
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 12 16:31 Seo
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 12 16:31 Social
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  12K Feb 26 09:56 sys
drwx------  2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 4.0K May 12 16:35 Taxonomy
```

As you can see, any directory that starts with uppercase is my own database. I don't care about logs at all as long as they are already inserted into the corresponding tables. And I don't care about MariaDB's infrastructure at all.

I want to backup files using a file-based backup plan. It's a script that uses `azcopy` from Microsoft Azure to put directories and files into the cloud.

Yet for a simple server with less than a thousand records, it consumes 200 MBs.

What files should I backup in the cloud to be able to restore later, other than my database directories?

**Update**
The reason I'm asking for this is because of cloud costs. We have a program that backs up many files to the cloud, and for the database, it backs up the whole `Databases` directory. This causes our bill to increase dramatically. Because we are a web design agency and we have hundreds of customers and if we calculate, we upload tens of Gigabytes of data each night for database backup.

Comment: The `ib_logfile0` is used during crash recovery to ensure data integrity. Without it, you're saying you're ok with potential data loss / corruption?

Comment: Do _not_ lose `ibdata1` -- that's where all your data is.

Comment: @RickJames, do you mean for a simple database MariaDB store 76 MBs of data? That seems extremely inefficient.

Comment: @J.D. I'm not OK with data corruption. I just don't want logs and time-based snapshots. I only want to be able to restore the latest data that follows ACID. In SQL Server, there was a logging configuration that would allow developers to use `Simple` model. I want something similar for MariaDB.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I know the `Simple Recovery Model` in SQL Server. Even then the Log file is still used, it's just truncated more frequently, which prevents it from growing as quickly. And a Full backup restore in SQL Server still restores that Log file (at whatever size it was when the Full backup was taken). I'm not sure if a similar Recovery Model feature exists in MariaDB, but if it does, I'm sure you'll still need to retain your `ib_logfile0`. I'm not sure how Log truncation works in MariaDB, but maybe your Log file isn't truncating properly, considering the size of it vs your # of rows.

Comment: In general, it is not a good idea to use file-based backup for databases, MySQL or not. It only works reliably if 1) you have a full snapshot of the data directory and 2) you suspend _all_ database updates while the backup is being taken. I suggest you use the database backup tools for your DBMS.

Comment: @mustaccio, that's why I asked here. I know SQL Server does not allow direct access to files even for copy while it's using those files. But MariaDB on Linux does. And if in theory all of the data is in those database files, and they are not dependent upon anything else, then why not?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati "*And if in theory all of the data is in those database files, and they are not dependent upon anything else, then why not?*" - To mustaccio's point, an operation may be actively running, and even updates the state of one file but not the other dependent files, during the same time you take a file-based backup, leaving you with an inconsistent set of the files in the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note in the [official documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/backup-and-restore-overview/) that there's no pick and choose on the suitable files to backup.

Note also that backups of files require a) mariadb syncronisation and b) an atomic snapshot of the filesystem.

For a few 1000 rows it seems like a logical backup would be smaller:

```
 mariadb-dump --flush-privileges --all-databases --routines --events --single-transaction | gzip -c > dump.sql.gz
```

And the other thing about backups, test a restore, people ask for more restores than backups.

Comment: For a `databases` directory that is 228 MBs, this resulted in a file that is only 1.2 MBs. This is amazing. How can I restore that file on another instance of MariaDB to ensure that it works correctly?

Comment: `zcat dump.sql.gz | mariadb`. The `mariadb` can be appended with  host/socket authentication to the other instance. The other instance can also be started with `--skip-grant-tables` as the dump will populate the entire instance.